# Any way for dehydrate() to share an object during an API call in tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

Is there any way for the dehydrate function in tastypie to share some variable? In any other framework, every request would create a new instance of the class, so we can use `self` to share data.

My use case: want to dehydrate objects returned by GET list with some additional data, but the request gets heavy due to the repeated db calls. Not everything is from a standard sql db, so `prefetch_related` will only take me so far.

```
class Meta:
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    # # wanted something like this
    # bundle.foo = self.cache['foo']
    # # but self is shared between all requests as an instance 
    # # of this class is declared while initializing, and I want 
    # # self.cache to be recreated for every request (without 
    # # potential races)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(EntryResource().urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used `bundle.request` to save data.
Basically:

```
try:
    bundle.request.cache
except AttributeError:
    bundle.request.cache = {}
```